# Can user hack values in action parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Example:

I have table Orders and table OrderPositions.

```
public partial class Orders
{
    public Orders()
    {
        this.OrderPositions = new HashSet<OrderPositions>();
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderPositions> OrderPositions { get; set; }
}

public partial class OrderPositions
{
    public int OrderPositionId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Orders Orders { get; set; }
}
```

On the view user **can modify single record from OrderPositions** table.
In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(OrderPositions orderPosition)
{
   // save orderPosition
}
```

So parameter orderPosition.Orders should be = null because on the form in view user can modify only order position. But can user hack it? I mean that in parameter orderPosition.Orders won't be null and I update record not only in table OrderPositions but also in table Orders? Or ASP.NET MVC prevent from that situation?

Comment: If you don't actually ever call orderPostions.Orders from your action method, it wouldn't matter if someone sent over "hacked" values or not.  However, this is one of the many reason using view models is preferred over using domain models.  If you do intend on using orderPositions.Orders, then yes, without validation, bad things could happen.

Comment: @Tommy - "from your action method" also includes whatever your ORM may do when you tell it to save changes.  This is the biggest source of unexpected problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what you do here

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(OrderPositions orderPosition)
{
   // save orderPosition
}
```

If you're saving the whole entity then yes there is nothing stopping a user passing over addition entity properties. There are a few ways to prevent this though, here are a couple...

**1.Create a new entity at the point of saving**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(OrderPositions orderPosition)
{

   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       var order = new OrderPositions
       {
          OrderPositionId = orderPosition.OrderPositionId,
          OrderId = orderPosition.OrderId,
          Name = orderPosition.Name
       };

       //Then save this new entity
   }
}
```

**2.Create a Model specific to the entity's action**

```
public class EditOrderPosition
{
    [Required]
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditOrderPosition model)
{

   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       var order = new OrderPositions
       {
          OrderPositionId = model.PositionId,
          OrderId = model.Id,
          Name = model.Name
       };

       //Then save this new entity
   }
}
```

I generally go with the 2nd method as it stops direct user involvement with my entities. As a rule of thumb I never use entity objects as parameters in controller actions.

Hope this helps

Comment: THX, very much for examplex - you helped me a lot, thx again :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes they can. This is one reason I do not expose my entities as a parameter to action methods, instead I use DTOs that only have the properties that I expect.

This is an example of the [Mass Assignment Vulnerability](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/12/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Comment: I would be a little more descriptive , give an example.  But by mentioning DTO you give OP something to google further

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is nothing preventing a rogue app calling your endpoint with arbitrary data.  Always validate everything serverside.